# Как реализуется параллельный I/O в стандартный поток или один файл?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, io

Хочу понять как реализован процесс чтение\записи в стандартные потоки или файл в частности интересно с++ и python.

1. Т.е. во время когда я вызываю stdin.read() и в этот момент в stdin лежит например 2 строки, блокируется ли запись в файл до того момента пока я не закончу чтение, или блокируется количество байт которые на начало чтение там содержаться, а другой поток может в это время записать например третью строчку сверху?
2. Как работает при этом база данных ведь например в ms sql это же фактически один файл, я так понимаю что много потоков в каждый момент блокируют какой то фрагмент файла и работают с ним.
   Я полистал несколько книжек по с++ и python но в основном везде написано только про то что можно открыть файл либо на чтение либо на запись и все.
   Если просто подскажите в какой книжке подробно можно почитать этого будет достаточно.

Comment: http://wgropp.cs.illinois.edu/courses/cs598-s15/lectures/lecture31.pdf у Gropp хорошее изложение многопоточных вещей. Скорее всего вам не помогут книги по языкам программированию, так как вы описываете задачи операционных систем. Поищите книги с названием Unix в заголовке, когда-то читал подобное.

Comment: Если речь по stdin stdout то наверное это относится в к ОС, но мы же так же можем и просто файл читать, например файл БД

Comment: а что если я скажу, что stdin и stdout это тоже файлы? :) В  каком-то (в очень приближённом) роде

Comment: Более того, они могут быть реальными файлами, если запустить программу с перенаправлением вроде `prog <file.txt` и в программе сделать что-то вроде `fstat(fileno(stdin), ...)` то прочитается информация о реальном файле

Comment: Почитать можно в [man lockf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf), [man fcntl](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) и **See Also** в них

Comment: Спасибо. 
1) Т.е. если не углубляться в конкретную реализацию, то суть именно такая что один процесс блокирует один фрагмент файла и работает с ним, другой другой фрагмент и за счет этого достигается параллельность?
2) Только еще хотел понять как определить конкретно stdin.read() например в Python блокирует запись в этот момент или запись может выполняться "поверх" фрагмента который в данный момент читают? Не могу найти информацию.